# Truck stopped starting after being jumped

Tags: jump-start

I have a 1985 c10 that has been having battery issues causing me to get a jump start everytime i want to start it up. Yesterday after a succesful jump start i was still  connected to my friends mini van she revered her engine and my truck died and now it wont start at all. What can be the problem?

Comment: Bad battery or corroded battery terminal connections.

Answer (score 1):

With the age of the car, could be lots of things, bad battery cable, bad starter (I had one just die and never came back) bad terminals or need to be cleaned, some cars have a special fuse (ie Honda Civic 1985 I think) and that could get blown if you aren't careful with a jump as I had that happen.

Inspect the battery cables, clean them, and I would have the battery and the alternator checked.  Auto Zone will check the battery and the alternator for no change, if you bring them into the store.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your alternator has now gone bad from struggling to charge a faulty battery. Most likely why it will not stay running any longer. Take the battery and alternator to a parts store and have them tested.